# In Flutter i want to replace .doc firebase with username or namecontroller

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

First of all i will be highly thankful to stackoverflow community you guys are great.
Problem:
i am using namecontroller for firebase username and password is

```
TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
```

TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

and here is authentication with firebase

```
 final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: nameController.text,
                          password: passwordController.text);
```

and here is code through i will save gps data to firebase firestone database

```
final loc.LocationData _locationResult = await location.getLocation();
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('location').doc('user1').set({
    'latitude': _locationResult.latitude,
    'longitude': _locationResult.longitude,
    'name': 'Bus No.1'
  }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

as .doc is created with name user1 and 'name' : 'Bus No.1'
i want to replace .doc firebase with username or namecontroller previously i used and also name field with same username is it possible
because lot of other user using this app so database save data separetely. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass the value to your function?

```
Future<void> setUserData(String docId, String name) async {

final loc.LocationData _locationResult = await location.getLocation();
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('location').doc(docId).set({
    'latitude': _locationResult.latitude,
    'longitude': _locationResult.longitude,
    'name': name
  }, SetOptions(merge: true));
}
```

Then call the function and pass the value in the controller, like this:

```
setUserData(user.id, nameController.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, It'll be better to save the document by userId which is unique for each user, hence avoiding reputation. It can be accessed using -

```
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
String uid = user!.uid;
```

So let's create the document for this user in Firestore!

```
/// from above example
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
String uid = user!.uid;

///name of user using nameController
String name = nameController.text;

final loc.LocationData _locationResult = await location.getLocation();
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('location').doc(uid).set({
    'latitude': _locationResult.latitude,
    'longitude': _locationResult.longitude,
    'name': name        <-- from TextEditingController()
  }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Congrats, you just made a firestore document with document-id same as that of user-id, which is unique and set a name property which could be used within your app.

now if you want to access name of current user,

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;  <-- null check is required
DocumentSnapshot document = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('location').doc(uid).get();
Map<String, dynamic> data = document.doc() as Map<String, dynamic>;

///lets say you want to get name
var name = data['name'];
```

read further by following this guide -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data